# The xml-rpc call to TestLink API method tl.reportTCResult failed

Tags: java, testlink

I am new on selenium and I need to integrate selenium with testlink for automated testing.
But getting exception:

> testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException:  The xml-rpc call to
>   TestLink API method tl.reportTCResult failed. Result[0] =
>   {message=(reportTCResult) - Parameter platformname OR platformid is
>   required, but has not been provided, code=200}

code:

```
public static void reportResult(String TestProject, String TestPlan, String Testcase, String Build, String Notes,
        String Result) throws TestLinkAPIException {
    TestLinkAPIClient api = new TestLinkAPIClient(DEVKEY, URL);

    api.reportTestCaseResult(TestProject, TestPlan, Testcase, Build ,Notes, Result);
}
```

Here I need to pass 1 more parameter but I don't know where to pass it and how to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause here is the limitation of the Testlink API. This API was created before the platform field is added into TestLink. For fixing this issue, just simple removing any platforms that are included in your test plan. Cheer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, i just found that there is one other TestlinkAPI from a Japanese author. It's made for TestLink 1.9.3-4 that could be fine with PlatformID field.